VBAの分岐処理について
VBAの関数すべてに分岐処理を入れてしまったのですが、これをすっきりさせる方法はないでしょうか？
ファイルAの処理　ファイルBの処理
Function　ブックを開く(ファイル＊）
    select case ファイルA
　　    //ファイルAの時のみの処理
    case ファイルB
       //ファイルAの時のみの処理
    end select
    //ブックを開く処理
end Function

Functon ブックの内容を集計する(ファイル*)
    select case ファイルA
　　    //ファイルAの時のみの処理
    case ファイルB
       //ファイルAの時のみの処理
    end select
    //ブックを集計する処理
End Function

Sub Main()
   ブックを開く(ファイルA）
　　ブックの内容を集計する(ファイルA)
End　Sub

実際にはこれより多くの関数があり、すべてをこのような処理にしてしまったので全体が把握しづらくなってしまいました。見通しを良くする良い方法はないでしょうか？

ブック内のシート・セルの形式・内容でまとまった塊になるでしょうから、呼ばれたFunction内で別々に判断するのではなく、形式・内容毎に１つのFunctionやSubにまとめれば良いのでは？ ちなみにこのサイトでは非推奨になる意見を求める質問に近そうなので質問内容をもう少し考えるか思い切って意見交換を受け入れる他のサイトで質問した方が良いかもしれません。どのような質問は避けるべきですか？ あとVBA コーディング規約で検索した例の一部。Visual Basic のコーディング規則, 今、VBAコーディング規約が熱い！, Excel VBAコーディング ガイドライン案

今後もこれらの関数を変更する予定はあるのでしょうか？もし無いのであれば今回はそのままにしておくという手もあると思います。変えるならファイル毎の関数にするぐらいでしょうか？

VBAでも、一応クラスの概念があります。
オブジェクト指向っぽく、設計/実装してみてはいかがでしょうか。
・共通インターフェース
' ファイル名：IFileHandler.cls（クラスモジュールとして作成する。）
Option Explicit

' ブックを開く処理のインターフェース
Public Sub ブックを開く()
End Sub

' ブックの内容を集計する処理のインターフェース
Public Sub ブックの内容を集計する()
End Sub

・ファイルA用のクラス
' ファイル名: ClsFileAHandler.cls（クラスモジュールとして作成する。）
Option Explicit
Implements IFileHandler

' ブックを開く処理（ファイルA専用）
Private Sub IFileHandler_ブックを開く()
    MsgBox "ファイルAを開く処理"
End Sub

' ブックの内容を集計する処理（ファイルA専用）
Private Sub IFileHandler_ブックの内容を集計する()
    MsgBox "ファイルAの内容を集計"
End Sub

・ファイルB用のクラス
' ファイル名: ClsFileBHandler.cls（クラスモジュールとして作成する。）
Option Explicit
Implements IFileHandler

' ブックを開く処理（ファイルB専用）
Private Sub IFileHandler_ブックを開く()
    MsgBox "ファイルBを開く処理"
End Sub

' ブックの内容を集計する処理（ファイルB専用）
Private Sub IFileHandler_ブックの内容を集計する()
    MsgBox "ファイルBの内容を集計"
End Sub

・実行用のMain関数
' ファイル名: MainModule.bas（標準モジュールとして作成する。）
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    ' ファイルA用のクラスのインスタンスを作成
    Dim handlerA As IFileHandler
    Set handlerA = New ClsFileAHandler
    ' ポリモーフィズムを利用して共通インターフェースから呼び出し
    handlerA.ブックを開く
    handlerA.ブックの内容を集計する

    ' ファイルB用のクラスのインスタンスを作成
    Dim handlerB As IFileHandler
    Set handlerB = New ClsFileBHandler
    ' ポリモーフィズムを利用して共通インターフェースから呼び出し
    handlerB.ブックを開く
    handlerB.ブックの内容を集計する
End Sub


「ファイルAの時のみの処理」の内容によっては関数の引数にシート名やセル範囲を追加することで、Select Case をなくすことができるかもしれません。
「ファイルAの時のみの処理」が「ブックを開く」関数と「ブックの内容を集計する」で同じ処理であれば、それを関数にして変数はモジュール変数として受け渡しできるかもしれません。
いずれにしても、処理内容がわからないので可能性だけですが。
また、Main 関数がありますが、VBAではあまりみかけません。
この中では ファイルA の処理しか記述がありませんが、ファイルB の処理はどのようにして実行するのでしょうか？

そもそも何をやりたいのか良くわかりません。
ファイルAがファイルBの時、「ファイルAの時のみの処理」を実行するのですか？
「ブックを開く」関数で実際に Select ～ End Select で何をやるのかを含めて簡単で良いので具体的に動作するコードを記述した方が良いと思います。
また、ファイルAというのはファイルのパスのことでしょうか、それとも Workbook オブジェクトのことでしょうか？
やりたいことがわからないのですが「ブックを開く」処理と「ブックの内容を集計する」処理は１つにはできないのでしょうか？
例えば、ファイルの場合分けをしてその中で共通の関数を呼ぶようにすることなどです。
